# Why do some of my SOAP::Data requests not get a response?

Tags: perl, soap

I am using to store data in table using [`SOAP::Lite`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SOAP::Lite) and [`SOAP::Data`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/SOAP::Data).

I am facing the issue where if I send 5 requests, I am only getting 2 or 3 or sometimes  zero responses.

What is the issue? How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, you probably want to enable SOAP tracing.

```
require SOAP::Lite;
SOAP::Lite::import(+trace => 'debug');
```

This will help you gather more information and diagnose what's going on at the SOAP layer.

Answer (score 2):

[`Acme::ESP`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Acme::ESP) should help.

In the absence of any concrete information or succinct code sample exhibiting the problem, that is the best answer.

[The posting guidelines for comp.lang.perl.misc](http://www.rehabitation.com/clpmisc/clpmisc_guidelines.html#how_to_participate__post__in_the_clpmisc_community) have good tips on how to compose a question that is likely to elicit useful responses (I know, this is not UseNet, but the advice is still useful).

You may also benefit from [esr's advice](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#beprecise).

If and when you post information that can actually help solve your problem, I will either update this answer with relevant help or delete it if I cannot provide it.

Comment: How can i use this for soap responses ?

Comment: @Sam Thanks for the upvote, but this answer does not deserve it (yet). I am trying to tell you that there isn't any information in your post that can help us solve your problem. One would have to be a mind reader to figure out what's wrong (thus, the ESP reference). Please provide more and concrete information.